# Pause and Resume the counting values from localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am using this code for countdown timer to a quiz test. Its working Fine. In this I need to add two buttons one is Pause button and another one is Resume button. When I click a Pause button it's stop time and when I click a Resume button it's start from where I pause the time.

I have tried this code. It's not working.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="div__time">
    <div style="display: none;" id="overall_time"></div>
    <div id="overall_times"></div>
    <div class="total_time"></div>
</div>
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
<input id="resumeButton" type="button" value="Resume">
```

**JS Code**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var speaking_ms = "00:00:10";
    var speaking_ms_arr = speaking_ms.split(":");
    var speaking_time_min_sec = (+speaking_ms_arr[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[1]) * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[2]);
    var speaking_time_min_sec = parseInt(speaking_time_min_sec) + 1;

    var speaking_value;

    if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter")) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter") <= 0) {
            speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
        } else {
            speaking_value = localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter");
        }
    } else {
        speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
    }

    document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;

    var speaking_counter = function() {
        if (speaking_value <= 0) {
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_time_min_sec);
        } else {
            speaking_value = parseInt(speaking_value) - 1;
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
        }
        document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;
        if (speaking_value == 0) {
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
            setTimeout(function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }, 1000);
        }

        var hours = Math.floor(speaking_value / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 % 60);
        var red_time = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
        document.getElementById('overall_times').innerHTML = red_time;
    };

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        speaking_counter();
    }, 1000);

    var Clock = {
        pause: function() {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                delete this.interval;
            },

            resume: function() {
                if (!this.interval) this.start();
            }
    };

    $('#pauseButton').click(function() { Clock.pause(); });
    $('#resumeButton').click(function() { Clock.resume(); });
</script>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhavanaditya/bohv0j9w/1/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since you save countdown state in local storage, you can save pause state too so countdown doesn't continue on page refresh when countdown was previously paused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the end of the code in the fiddle and it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/bohv0j9w/5/

```
    var Clock = {
        pause: function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
            },

            resume: function() {
                if (!interval) interval = setInterval(speaking_counter, 1000);
            }
    };

document.querySelector('#pauseButton').addEventListener("click", Clock.pause);
document.querySelector('#resumeButton').addEventListener("click", Clock.resume);
```

In your version this.internal is undefined you may want to learn about "this" and scopes in js. And $(...) is a syntax that requires the lib jquery (not included in the fiddle), the vanilla js equivalent is "document.querySelector", you should read the MDN article about this function.
Finally, your syntax is a bit old school. If you use localStorage you aren't targeting very old browsers maybe you should avoid jquery and use keywords such as "const".

Answer (score 1):

Following are your mistakes. ([Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bohv0j9w/6/))

```
var Clock = {
    pause: function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);//(this.interval is undefined, replace it with interval)
                          ^^^^
            delete this.interval;//(this.interval is undefined, replace it with interval)
                   ^^^^
        },

        resume: function() {
            if (!this.interval) this.start();//(this.interval is undefined, replace it typeof interval === undefined to check whether interval exists or not)
                 ^^^^
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ //(this.start() is also not defined, replace it with start() and move `var interval = setInterval(fun.....` into new start function)
        }
};
```

look at following code.

```
var speaking_ms = "00:00:10";
var speaking_ms_arr = speaking_ms.split(":");
var speaking_time_min_sec = (+speaking_ms_arr[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[1]) * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[2]);
var speaking_time_min_sec = parseInt(speaking_time_min_sec) + 1;

var speaking_value;

if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter") <= 0) {
        speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
    } else {
        speaking_value = localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter");
    }
} else {
    speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
}

document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;

var speaking_counter = function() {
    if (speaking_value <= 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_time_min_sec);
    } else {
        speaking_value = parseInt(speaking_value) - 1;
        localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
    }
    document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;
    if (speaking_value == 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
        setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 1000);
    }

    var hours = Math.floor(speaking_value / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 % 60);
    var red_time = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
    document.getElementById('overall_times').innerHTML = red_time;
};

var start = function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
      speaking_counter();
  }, 1000);
}

var Clock = {
    pause: function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
            delete interval;
        },

        resume: function() {
            if (typeof interval === 'undefined') start();
        }
};

$('#pauseButton').click(function() { Clock.pause(); });
$('#resumeButton').click(function() { Clock.resume(); });
start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your solution and implemented what you were trying to implement. There were minor issues with your solution which i fixed.
1. You were using this to access interval variable that was not part of the clock object in which you were accessing the variable.
2. You were using this.start() function in the resume function of clock object which was not part of the clock object.
3. JQuery used to define events was not included in the fiddle. Although it is included in the code pasted in the question.
html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="div__time">
    <div style="display: none;" id="overall_time"></div>
    <div id="overall_times"></div>
    <div class="total_time"></div>
</div>
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
<input id="resumeButton" type="button" value="Resume">
</body>
```

js:

```
 var speaking_ms = "00:00:10";
    var speaking_ms_arr = speaking_ms.split(":");
    var speaking_time_min_sec = (+speaking_ms_arr[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[1]) * 60 + (+speaking_ms_arr[2]);
    var speaking_time_min_sec = parseInt(speaking_time_min_sec) + 1;

    var speaking_value;

    if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter")) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter") <= 0) {
            speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
        } else {
            speaking_value = localStorage.getItem("speaking_counter");
        }
    } else {
        speaking_value = speaking_time_min_sec;
    }

    document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;

    var speaking_counter = function() {
        if (speaking_value <= 0) {
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_time_min_sec);
        } else {
            speaking_value = parseInt(speaking_value) - 1;
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
        }
        document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;
        if (speaking_value == 0) {
            localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
            setTimeout(function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }, 1000);
        }

        var hours = Math.floor(speaking_value / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 % 60);
        var red_time = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
        document.getElementById('overall_times').innerHTML = red_time;
    };

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        speaking_counter();
    }, 1000);


    var Clock = {
        pause: function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
                delete interval;
            },

            resume: function() {

                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                        speaking_counter();
                    }, 1000);

            }
    };

    $('#pauseButton').click(function() { Clock.pause(); });
    $('#resumeButton').click(function() { Clock.resume(); });
```

Here is the fiddle link: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d62o98wh/)

Answer (score 1):

You have gotten quite a few answers so far, I wanted to give you another example so that you have an alternative architecture to consider. Definitely read up on [`scopes` and `closures`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures) and the use of [`this`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes). Also, you don't need jQuery for this function. Only import a large library like jQuery when you need it. In this case `document.getElementById` does you well, as does `addEventListener`.

There are even more exciting ways to handle a countdown (including the use of recursion), but below is an example of envisioning your Clock as a single object. This gives you greater control over the clock and it makes it reusable.

You can define functions on the clock that manage the interval, decrement the countdown, pause, resume, start and reset the clock. I added buttons for each so you can see how it would work. Also note that I commented out `localStorage` to show that it works without storage, but mainly because the snippets in StackOverflow aren't given permission to use `localStorage` so it would crash, but you can run this code here as is.

```js
var Clock = {
  speaking_value: 10,
  interval: -1,
  countdown: function() {
    speaking_value = this.speaking_value;
    if (speaking_value <= 0) {
      //localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", 0);
    } else {
      speaking_value = parseInt(speaking_value) - 1;
      //localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
    }
    document.getElementById('overall_time').innerHTML = speaking_value;
    if (speaking_value == 0) {
    //localStorage.setItem("speaking_counter", speaking_value);
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(self.interval);
      }, 1000);
    }
    this.speaking_value = speaking_value;
    this.updateClock();
  }, 
  paused: false,
  pause: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.paused = true;
  },
  resume: function() {
    if (this.paused) { 
      this.paused = false;
      this.tick();    
    }
  },
  updateClock: function() {
    speaking_value = this.speaking_value;
    var hours = Math.floor(speaking_value / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(speaking_value % 3600 % 60);
    var red_time = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
    document.getElementById('overall_times').innerHTML = red_time;
  },
  tick: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      self.countdown()
    }, 1000)
  },
  start: function() {
    this.updateClock();
    this.tick();
  },
  reset: function(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.speaking_value = 10;
    this.updateClock();
  }
};

Clock.updateClock();

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function() { Clock.start(); });

document.getElementById('pauseButton').addEventListener('click', function() { Clock.pause(); });

document.getElementById('resumeButton').addEventListener('click', function() { Clock.resume(); });

document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', function() { Clock.reset(); });
```

```html
<div class="div__time">
    <div style="display: none;" id="overall_time"></div>
    <div id="overall_times"></div>
    <div class="total_time"></div>
</div>
<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
<input id="resumeButton" type="button" value="Resume">
<input id="resetButton" type="button" value="Reset">
```